# Is it possible to “inherit” a green card?

Tags: usa, greencard, ancestry-visas

If one of my divorced parents has been granted a green card but does not reside in the US (and has not resided there for longer than a few months), does that have any bearing on an application that I - a European citizen - make for residency?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is unlikely that the fact that your parent holds a US green card will have any bearing on your application. In fact, if your parent does not currently reside in the US, their status of "permanent residency" could certainly be called into question (but also wouldn't affect your application).

This happened to somebody I knew in Canada many years ago. He was Canadian, was entering the US from Canada, and the immigration officer noticed his green card in his wallet. After some brief questioning, the officer established that he did not live in the US and cancelled his green card on the spot.

Comment: "...and cancelled his green card on the spot" - wow, they can do that? I was aware that green-card status could be revoked if the holder is no longer resident in the US, but was not aware it could happen so "unilaterally". Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @davek It certainly can happen--if they figure out that you haven't met the requirements they cancel it.

Comment: @davek they normally ask you to relinquish it.  CBP [cannot rescind permanent resident status unilaterally; they have to get the alien to do it voluntarily, or else they have to refer the case to an immigration judge](http://lawandborder.com/risk-abandoning-green-card-abroad-6-months/#8_What_Will_Happen_in_the_Airport_if_the_CBP_Officer_Suspects_Abandonment).

Comment: @LorenPechtel no it can't happen without the alien's consent; see my previous comment.  They typically talk the alien into abandoning it voluntarily, but the alien has a right to a hearing before an immigration judge.